# PHP WebSocket wss

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, wss

For a project I have to setup a web and websocket server. I do have an ssl certificate (self signed) but I can't (even after a lot of google and stackoverflow) get wss to work. Does anyone here have a good resource that explains some things about this? I tried with stunnel forwarding but that didn't workout for me. I forgot where I found the library but the websocket class name is ws api.php (with the space included)

Comment: show all the code you tried so for. Then only we can help you.

Comment: I didn't keep track of all the code I used to be honest, I tried about every google result (10 pages) so I could look that up again if you'd like? I was kinda of hoping to get a link to a simple explanation or something like that

Comment: I figured out how to do this but I was using tomcat.

Comment: I've had good success using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) Web Socket server for PHP. However, this site is not for recommending outside resources, so unless you provide some code that isn't working and ask a specific question about how to get it to work, I feel this quesiton is off topic.

Comment: also, fyi, it looks like your original package you were using may have been [php-websocket-server](https://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/) (hosted over at Google code)

Comment: I used that library indeed and to redefine my question in that case: How would I get wss to work with php-websocket-server?